# problem with fs.readFile on remote? (works locally but not on server)

Tags: node.js, json, server, bots, discord.js

The code below is for a random quote generator for a Discord bot and has been stripped for easy reading, the problem I have is that on my 'dev machine' ( enthusiast/hobbyist btw ) the code works really well, but when uploaded to my droplet (ubuntu 18.04, node v8.15) it does nothing, not even an error is returned.

```
const fs = require("fs");

exports.run = async (client, message, args) => { 

if (!args || args.length > 0) return message.reply("No need for multiple inputs");

fs.readFile("./quotes.json", "utf8", function(err, data) {
const obj = JSON.parse(data);
const result = obj[Math.floor(Math.random() * obj.length)];


message.channel.send(result.quote);
 });
 };
```

When the code is on the droplet and I remove the fs.readfile and JSON.parse block and hard-code a reply into `message.channel.send("it works")` it does return the message as expected, I would appreciate someone casting an eye over things and advising whether it is a code problem or possibly a server config issue.

**Working Code Below**

tbh, I'm still unaware of what the issue was so I just rewrote it all on a new file in less than 10 minutes.. changed a few variable names is about all I did really other than adding in `__dirname +`

```
fs.readFile(__dirname + "/maiq-quotes.json", "utf8", function(err, data) {

const quotesobj = JSON.parse(data);

var quote = quotesobj[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotesobj.length)];

console.log(quote);
message.channel.send(quote.quote);

});
```

Comment: You seem to have included the answer in your question. Are you still having a problem, or did you solve it yourself? If you solved it yourself, you should post the answer as an actual answer below, not as part of the question. If you're still having a problem, it's unclear what exactly you're looking for in the way of answers.

Comment: @CodyGray yes I have, it was sometime after (almost two days) since making the original post that I fixed things up as explained in my update to the post. No major changes in code as you can see, nothing changed on the server, more or less it fixed itself with a newly written file even though the problematic one was checked out numerous times for correct ftp upload format, lf line breaks etc,I did attempt to mark as answered/fixed but it won't let you (for obvious reasons) accept your own answer.

Comment: Yes, you are allowed to accept your own answer. Answering your own question is even encouraged. You just have to wait a couple of days before you can accept your own answer.

Comment: You can import a json without necessary reading from file. You can do an import statement like this: `const quotes = require('./quotes.json');`. In this way you have an already json parsed json in the var `quotes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little bit weird that there is no error, however double check the file is in the correct place (an error should be thrown for this though if it can't find it) and also check the permissions on the file with `ls -l`.

Comment: thanks for the reply @Pentium1080Ti , those were the very first things i did, infact i went so far as to chmod from 644 to 755. JSON file location is correct also. Since I made this post originally i have sent a couple of other really basic files up one thats a simple fs read of a txt file and then another that just pings a message straightback on file execute no other code in there. The file which pings back works, the other file with a simple fs.readFile of a txt file does not. All other files (100 or so work great). Linebreaks have been checked and are lf and all files utf8.. baffled!

Comment: I've accepted this as the answer, although I did repeatedly check file permissions, file encoding, line breaks and file upload type via ftp, It transpired that creating a new file with a few very minor code changes (those changes are appended to the original post) that in no way should have differed the outcome resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna do:

```
fs.readFile("./quotes.json", "utf8", function(err, data) {
    if(err) console.log(err);
```

So that it shows you the Error

Comment: as i said in the opening post i stripped it down for readability, while i was running the problem code i had this in originally `if (err) {
    console.error(err)
    return
  }
  console.log(data)`